# Snowflake CLI does not process control characters correctly (^C^Z)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I run the Snowflake CLI and it is returning a large result set, if I press Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Z, it does not have the normal behaviors of either breaking the program or pushing it to the background where I could then kill it manually.

**How can I get Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Z to work correctly on the Snowflake CLI?**

This is in a Linux environment.  And well-behaved command line tools should behave as described above.

The exact command is 'snowsql'.  I'm using the standard SNOWSQL_* environmental variables to send the CLI configuration information.

The big result set is often the result of me asking for more data than I intended.  So it's mostly about dumb user error, but still, we all do it.

This is not a problem if it's a long running query.  Long queries easily break with Ctrl-C.

Is there some kind of setting?  That setting could either be in Snowflake, or something strange I'm doing in my bash session--though no other major CLIs are having issues.

If this is normal product behavior, I'd appreciate confirmation of that to.  If that is the case, I'll submit a product enhancement request.

Workaround are acceptable.  If this is just how snowsql will behave, I'm open to Bash tricks since it would be easy enough to "wrap" the snowsql in a function.

Comment: Note that this same behavior occurs when you don't have environmental variables defined or the config file set up.  It will prompt you with "Account:" and if you try to Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Z at that point, it just keeps prompting you.  Again, standard behavior should be the break or background the job respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution, but **using 'rlwrap' will at least handle Ctrl-Z as desired**, which then makes it easy to kill.  Just do something like this:

```
rlwrap snowsql --foo --bar
```

Using whatever parameters you need of course.

When you press Ctrl-Z, it will immediately push the job to the background.  From there, kill it like any other job.

Still a bit more work than just handling the characters correctly, but it's a decent work-around.

The 'rlwrap' command is a little utility that I've used in a number of situations that have strange CLI behavior.  I'm not sure what it's intended to do, but it handles Ctrl-* characters the way you'd expect, and it can make the arrow keys behave better in some situations.

I've even used rlwrap to make my own command prompts.  E.g. S3 has brutal syntax, so I wrote an S3 prompt for myself using rlwrap, and it's because of rlwrap that all the control and arrow keys work right in that handy little home-grown prompt.

For snowcli, rlwrap is a decent workaround.